# Rails app has trouble with inter-model saving

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm working on an app that downloads meta tags from websites and saves then.  The downloading happens in a model called `Site`.  I'd like to save off the downloaded robots meta tags into a model called `robots_tag` which is connected to sites via a join table called `meta_tag_sites`.

But the method that I've written in the sites model to do this isn't working.  When I try to call the method in the console, I get the following error.

> undefined method `robots_meta=' for []:ActiveRecord::Relation

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

```
class Site < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :domain 
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :meta_tag_sites
  has_many :robots_tags, through: :meta_tag_sites
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :robots_tags

  # ...

  def download_robots_meta_tags
    robots_tags = Nokogiri::HTML(Net::HTTP.get(self.domain, "/")).xpath("//meta[@name='robots']")
    robots_tags.each do |tag|
      self.robots_tags.robots_meta = tag
    end
  end

  # ...

end

class RobotsTag < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :robots_meta
  has_many :meta_tag_sites
  has_many :sites, through: :meta_tag_sites
end

class MetaTagSite < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :site_id, :meta_tag_id
  belongs_to :site
  belongs_to :robots_tag
end
```

(BTW, this post is related to an earlier post: [Web-scraping Rails App Getting Over-Modelled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11156951/web-scraping-rails-app-getting-over-modelled)).

Comment: You have some syntax errors above. For example: `attr_accessible :domain,` should not end with a comma. Also, for style purposes, `# ...` looks a lot better than a plain `...`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
self.robots_tags.robots_meta = tag
```

`self.robots_tags` is a *collection* of objects defined by `has_many :robots_tags`, and you're attempting to assign a specific attribute to that entire collection. You can't do this. If you want to assign to an attribute on a specific object, you have to either iterate over the collection, or select a specific object from the collection via `first` or `last` or any of the other `Enumerable` methods.

Answer (score 1):

By inspection, the offending line appears to be:

```
self.robots_tags.robots_meta = tag
```

You should iterate over `self.robots_tags` instead, with something like:

```
self.robots_tags.each do |robot_tag|
  robot_tag.robots_meta = tag
end
```