# Rails models not talking with each other. Not sure how to add records to one model from within another

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm working on an app that does some web scraping.  In the sites model, I've got this method:

```
  def download_meta_tags
    downloaded_tags = Nokogiri::HTML(Net::HTTP.get(self.domain, "/")).xpath("//meta[@name='robots']")
    downloaded_tags.each do |t|
      self.robots_tags.tag << t
    end
  end
```

The sites model has many robots_tags through a join table called robots_tag_sites. The sites model also accepts_nested_attributes_for :robots_tags. The method above is meant to take all the tags that get downloaded in line 1 of the method and save them off to the tags column of the robots_tags table.

I think the problem is that "self.robots_tags" still grabs a collection of things instead of one individual thing. But I'm not sure how to add the tag correctly.  Any advice?

(BTW, these is a follow up from another post, [Rails app has trouble with inter-model saving](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11159197/rails-app-has-trouble-with-inter-model-saving))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be using `self.robots_tags.create(...)` to create a new `RobotTag` object.

Assuming your `RobotTag` has a `tag` attribute, it might look something like this:

```
downloaded_tags.each do |t|
  self.robot_tags.create(:tag => t)
end
```

Comment: Thank you!  I've been working on this method for a while now and I was starting to lose hope!  I'm a little embarrassed that the solution was that simple.  But mostly I'm just grateful for the helping hand.  Thanks!